# Migrating from SQL Server to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm migrating a SQL Server database that has `sql_variant` columns to a MySql database.

What's the equivalent of this type in the MySql world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no equivalent datatype in MySQL.
This is why one should wehere ever possible rely on the ANSI standard and not use provider specific types, functions, ...

Depending on the content of this columns (if no binary content was inserted) you could use varchar I guess.